# How to auto-update a PWA with the currently deployed manifest/assets

Tags: html, webpack, web-deployment, progressive-web-apps

We have a PWA ReactJS app packaged with webpack and pushed to s3 for deployment. Due to the nature of the app, users stay on the app for days and never end up closing/refreshing the page.

When we deploy, the new index.html pointing to the new production assets are updated in the s3 bucket. But, because the user is not closing/refreshing the page, the users are stuck in the old version and sometimes that leads to breaking features. How do i get the currently open tab to fetch the new manifest/assets and work with them instead of the old ones, without getting stuff done by user manually?

Just to be clear, I know this way exists:

> Query the server whether an update is available, show a dialog the the
>   user when update is available, run window.location.reload(true) and
>   store the new versionString in localStorage

**I am trying to figure out a way to update the assets in the background without the need to refresh.**

Comment: That's a strange behavior, see, in PWA browsers caches all the files and saves those in the browser so no needs to reload sames files again when the user reloads the page, but every time you make changes on files those files names change too, if you open your dev tool/network on your browser will see tthat names of the files are something like main.31a319f.css they haves these numbers that will change if the file has been modified so the cache will reload it as it was a new file and so the user could see new changes. Hope this could help you.

Comment: Ok I have such idea. You need to add some event e.g. `updateAssets` to your SW.js and triger it from backend when you whant to update your files (here is a number of insturments for such action, [here is some](https://pusher.com/)). On that event you need to triger some event for your `main.js` file
`var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('updateAssets', function(data) {
  // pass event to `main.js`
});`. And inside your main.js you have to update all what you whant by yourself ( I beleive it would be hard but not imposible).